# How to commit two neighboring folders in one revision

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Please consider this folder structure on the client:

```
+ ParentFolder
   + ChildFolder A
   + ChildFolder B
   + Some 20 odd other folders that should not be in svn
```

now how I arrived at my current situation:

1. Imported ChildFolder A into SVN
2. Did some revisions
3. found out there was related code in ChildFolder B
4. Imported B into SVN

In SVN it now looks like this:

```
server/MyRepository
+ ChildFolder A
+ ChildFolder B
```

Now it turns out that the solution to an issue touch files in both A and B. Can I commit them in one revision?

I can commit them seperatley but then changes would be split into 2 revisions: one for the commit of A and one for B. That would make it harder to oversee all the changes that were made to resolve an issue.

Basically I'd like to right-click op ParentFolder and do 'SVN Commit'. But ParentFolder is not under source control.

Is there any (responsible) way now to enable me to commit changes from both folders in one commit?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit should look like this:

```
ChildFolder A(and contents) deleted
ChildFolder B(and contents) deleted
ParentFolder (along with contents of A and B within) added
```

SVN should be smart enough (though I'm not 100% certain) that it can keep track of the contents of the child folders through the move.

Comment: Would that also add the 20 odd folders that have data? Or can I let svn ignore them?

Comment: Ah, I missed that part of your question. You could either delete the directory that shouldn't be there, or if it is compiled stuff you can use the svn:ignore property to ignore the directories.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this in our sandbox environment